# How can i retrieve the Product Name from a Opportunity in Salesforce SOQL?

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have created an Opportunity in Salesforce with Opportunity Line Items.
I run the following query and the

```
SELECT Amount, Account.Name, Account.AccountNumber, Name, 
(
  SELECT Quantity, UnitPrice, ProductCode,  Product2.Name FROM 
  OpportunityLineItems
)
FROM Opportunity
```

The OpportunityLineItems  column returned in the result are as follows.

```
  [{"Quantity":"1","UnitPrice":"10","ProductCode":"code1","Product2":"[object Object]"}]
```

If i drill down to the opportunity in Salesforce UI I see Under Products(Test Price Book) the Line.
If i drill down into the line the Name is name1.
So why is it returning [object Object] and not the name as requested by the query ?

Answer (score 0):

It probably returns the results fine, it's just your connecting library that messes up and shows JavaScript object placeholder instead of actual nested object. I've seen it also show up in Salesforce's own Developer Console.

What do you use? A raw REST API call (using [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) -> utilities -> rest explorer, Postman or something else) should produce this

(I added a WHERE clause)

```
/services/data/v52.0/query?q=SELECT+Amount,+Account.Name,+Account.AccountNumber,+Name,++(+++SELECT+Quantity,+UnitPrice,+ProductCode,++Product2.Name+FROM++++OpportunityLineItems+)+FROM+Opportunity+WHERE+Id+IN+(SELECT+OpportunityId+FROM+OpportunityLineItem)+LIMIT+5
```

[image]

If you really connect from javascript - see if you can JSON.stringify(results) or something like that before logging it, should give you better structure? Or step through the code with debugger...

But no, the data should be there all right, just doesn't render well on your end.

Comment: I actually did the query as follows and it worked as expected                                                       
SELECT  Opportunity.Amount, Opportunity.Account.Name, Opportunity.Account.AccountNumber,  
Opportunity.Name , Quantity, UnitPrice, ProductCode, PriceBookEntry.Name   
FROM OpportunityLineItem
   where OpportunityId in (select Id from Opportunity)

Comment: Yep, it works too but there will be subtle differences. This goes "up" from line items to oppty. What if you'll ever have to query an opportunity that doesn't have any line items. Or maybe you'll have to get oppty + line items + more related data (stage history? Related orders? Delivery/payment schedules?). You won't be able to do it with 2nd query. 1st form is more natural for "header +line items"